# Solution for search objects in date range

Tags: search

I'm building some sort of house booking website, and I'm looking for some search engine/database-algorithm that can filter objects based on house availability dates

so let's say I have House1(available dates: Jan1...Jan7, Jan20, Jan23)

And if I query all objects for dates Jan2-Jan3 - I should find that object, and if I query Jan6-Jan8 - I should find it

(Note: in database I have thousands of objects and also various search filters, and search should work fast)

Comment: Are you using an SQL database?

Comment: Data is stored in SQL database, but we can use some solution only for search index that can be on some other engine (sorl, elasticsearch, mongo)

Answer (score 0):

Processing 'thousands of objects' takes milliseconds with indexing in SQL. I know the below is simple enough to do in MySQL / SQL-Server.

Structure: (pseudo-code)

```
House(ID INT, ...)
Availability(ID INT, HouseID INT, Start DATETIME, Finish DATETIME)
/* Index on Availability (Start, Finish) */
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.ID, ...
FROM House H JOIN Availability A ON A.HouseID = H.ID
WHERE A.Start <= @DesiredFinish AND @DesiredStart <= A.Finish
```

This will return all houses that overlap availability with the specified dates.